# EmergenceDoc.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol

Tags: c++, mfc

I' m creating a simple MFC text editor in VS2010 in order to learn C++ and I've hit a bit of a stumbling block....

Specifically, I get the following error in my build log:

```
1>  Generating Code...
1>Link:
1>     Creating library C:\Users\Alvin\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Emergence\Debug\EmergenceHandlers.lib and object C:\Users\Alvin\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Emergence\Debug\EmergenceHandlers.exp
1>EmergenceDoc.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall CEmergenceCntrItem::CEmergenceCntrItem(struct _reobject *,class CEmergenceDoc *)" (??0CEmergenceCntrItem@@QAE@PAU_reobject@@PAVCEmergenceDoc@@@Z) referenced in function "public: virtual class CRichEditCntrItem * __thiscall CEmergenceDoc::CreateClientItem(struct _reobject *)const " (?CreateClientItem@CEmergenceDoc@@UBEPAVCRichEditCntrItem@@PAU_reobject@@@Z)
1>C:\Users\Alvin\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Emergence\Debug\EmergenceHandlers.dll : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
1> 
1>Build FAILED.
1>
1>Time Elapsed 00:00:06.52
========== Rebuild All: 1 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Below are all the files in which CEmergenceCntrItem appears....

cntritem.h:

```
#include "afxrich.h"
#include "Resource.h"
class CEmergenceDoc;
class CEmergenceView;

class CEmergenceCntrItem : public CRichEditCntrItem
{
    DECLARE_SERIAL(CEmergenceCntrItem)

public:
    CEmergenceCntrItem(REOBJECT* preo = NULL, CEmergenceDoc* pContainer = NULL);

public:
    CEmergenceDoc* GetDocument()
        { return (CEmergenceDoc*)COleClientItem::GetDocument(); }
    CEmergenceView* GetActiveView()
        { return (CEmergenceView*)COleClientItem::GetActiveView(); }

    // ClassWizard generated virtual function overrides
    //{{AFX_VIRTUAL(CWordPadCntrItem)
    public:
    protected:
    //}}AFX_VIRTUAL

// Implementation
public:
#ifdef _DEBUG
        virtual void AssertValid() const;
    virtual void Dump(CDumpContext& dc) const;
#endif
};
```

EmergenceView.cpp:

```
#include "afxrich.h"
#pragma once

class CEmergenceCntrItem;

class CEmergenceView : public CRichEditView
{
protected: // create from serialization only
    CEmergenceView();
    DECLARE_DYNCREATE(CEmergenceView)

public:
    CEmergenceDoc* GetDocument() const;

public:

public:
    virtual void OnDraw(CDC* pDC);  // overridden to draw this view
    virtual BOOL PreCreateWindow(CREATESTRUCT& cs);
protected:
    virtual BOOL OnPreparePrinting(CPrintInfo* pInfo);
    virtual void OnBeginPrinting(CDC* pDC, CPrintInfo* pInfo);
    virtual void OnEndPrinting(CDC* pDC, CPrintInfo* pInfo);

public:
    virtual ~CEmergenceView();
#ifdef _DEBUG
        virtual void AssertValid() const;
    virtual void Dump(CDumpContext& dc) const;
#endif

protected:

protected:
    afx_msg void OnFilePrintPreview();
    afx_msg void OnRButtonUp(UINT nFlags, CPoint point);
    afx_msg void OnContextMenu(CWnd* pWnd, CPoint point);
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
public:
    afx_msg void OnMutateGroup();
};

#ifndef _DEBUG  // debug version in EmergenceView.cpp
inline CEmergenceDoc* CEmergenceView::GetDocument() const
   { return reinterpret_cast<CEmergenceDoc*>(m_pDocument); }
#endif
```

EmergenceDoc.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Emergence.h"

#include "EmergenceDoc.h"
#include "CntrItem.h"

#ifdef _DEBUG
#define new DEBUG_NEW
#undef THIS_FILE
static char THIS_FILE[] = __FILE__;
#endif

IMPLEMENT_DYNCREATE(CEmergenceDoc, CRichEditDoc)

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CEmergenceDoc, CRichEditDoc)
    //{{AFX_MSG_MAP(CMyWordDoc)
        // NOTE - the ClassWizard will add and remove mapping macros here.
        //    DO NOT EDIT what you see in these blocks of generated code!
    //}}AFX_MSG_MAP
    // Enable default OLE container implementation
    ON_UPDATE_COMMAND_UI(ID_OLE_EDIT_LINKS, 
    CRichEditDoc::OnUpdateEditLinksMenu)
    ON_COMMAND(ID_OLE_EDIT_LINKS, CRichEditDoc::OnEditLinks)
    ON_UPDATE_COMMAND_UI_RANGE(ID_OLE_VERB_FIRST, 
    ID_OLE_VERB_LAST, CRichEditDoc::OnUpdateObjectVerbMenu)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

CEmergenceDoc::CEmergenceDoc()
{
}

CEmergenceDoc::~CEmergenceDoc()
{
}

BOOL CEmergenceDoc::OnNewDocument()
{
    if (!CRichEditDoc::OnNewDocument())
        return FALSE;
    return TRUE;
}
CRichEditCntrItem* CEmergenceDoc::CreateClientItem(REOBJECT* preo) const
{
    return new CEmergenceCntrItem(preo, (CEmergenceDoc*) this);
}

void CEmergenceDoc::Serialize(CArchive& ar)
{
    CRichEditDoc::Serialize(ar);
}
```

CntrItem.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Emergence.h"

#include "EmergenceDoc.h"
#include "EmergenceView.h"
#include "cntritem.h"

#ifdef _DEBUG
#undef THIS_FILE
static char BASED_CODE THIS_FILE[] = __FILE__;
#endif

IMPLEMENT_SERIAL(CEmergenceCntrItem, CRichEditCntrItem, 0)

CEmergenceCntrItem::CEmergenceCntrItem(REOBJECT *preo, CEmergenceDoc* pContainer)
    : CRichEditCntrItem(preo, pContainer)
{
}

#ifdef _DEBUG
void CEmergenceCntrItem::AssertValid() const
{
        CRichEditCntrItem::AssertValid();
}

void CEmergenceCntrItem::Dump(CDumpContext& dc) const
{
    CRichEditCntrItem::Dump(dc);
}
#endif
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have the compiler dump preprocessed files and see what `REOBJECT` evaluates to when compiling the c'tor of `CEmergenceCntrItem`. You can instruct MSC to output preprocessed files by specifying the compiler switch [/P (Preprocess to a File)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8z9z0bx6.aspx). ALL UPPERCASE usually indicates a preprocessor macro - it may not be what it looks like. -- On a second thought: The `#pragma once` in your .cpp file doesn't look right. The lack of include guards in your header doesn't look right either.

Comment: CEmergenceCntrItem(REOBJECT* preo = 0, CEmergenceDoc* pContainer = 0);

Comment: so i'm guessing REOBJECT evauluates to 0, though i'm not sure what this means.....

Comment: This is not preprocessed output; it's your c'tor declaration, with default arguments. If you're not providing a pointer in a call, a `nullptr` will be used. This is not an issue.

Comment: I'm not sure how to get thre preprocessed output. I tried /P and looked in the EmergenceDoc.i file that was generated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just copy cntritem.cpp and cntritem.h to resources folder!